# JQuery - Rounded corners

Tags: jquery, curvycorners

My intentions for my site are to add curvy corners..
Does anyone know if there is a way to make curvy corners round the corners of every element on the page...
if that is the case how do you do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a jQuery-specific solution?

Comment: well any script that automatically makes everything have rounded corners and keep their borders and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need JavaScript for this, you can do it with CSS - although IE6 wont support this. For all browsers you will need to use images.

Try this:

```
.round{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;
}

<div class="round etc etc"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this for ie 6 too and all cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

As @JLeagle pointed out already, you can use CSS to achieve this in most browsers.

If you *do* need support for older browsers there's a nifty [jQuery Curvy Corners plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/curvy-corners) you can use:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/curvy-corners

Comment: can you please tell me how to make curvy corners automatically do all content of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option: [CSS3 Solution](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)
If you want to support older browsers (e.g. IE6), you'll have to use images.
Not sure how/why would you do this with jQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="#my-element">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-element{
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius:15px;
  border-radius: 15px; /*Future proofing*/
}
```

OR:

jQuery:

```
$('#my-element').css({
 -moz-border-radius: 15px, 
 -webkit-border-radius:15px,
  border-radius: 15px
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no general solution to this, for lots of reasons, because you will have elements of different sizes, and you will want their corner radii to be appropriate to their size, but mainly because you have cross-browser issues to deal with.

So my oppinion is that there is no single answer to your question, and it's too vague to be answered here.